# Finding out whether a date is within y days of the value entered in a cell

Tags: vba, date

```
    'checks to see if date is within x days of the inputted date
Function isFutureDate(x) As Boolean   
    Dim daysFuture As Integer
    Dim futureDate As Date
    daysFuture = Sheet1.Range("e1").Value - 1
    'we have to add one to not count today
    futureDate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, daysFuture) 
    If x >= Date And x < futureDate Then
        isFutureDate = True
    Else
        isFutureDate = False
    End If
End Function

    'checks to see if date is in the past x days
Function isPastDate(x) As Boolean   
    Dim BDate As Date
    Dim y As Date
    Dim daysPast As Integer
    'subtract one to not count today
    daysPast = Sheet1.Range("E1").Value - 1 'subtract one to not count today

    BDate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1 * daysPast)
    If x < Date And x > BDate Then
        isPastDate = True
    Else
        isPastDate = False
    End If
End Function
```

These are the two functions I have currently. x is passed as a Date. When I step through the program, I notice an error with BDate in the isPastDate function. In my file, I have a cell where the user enters how many days in the future they would like to see entries for. I think this is where my main problem is. When I check the value of daysFuture or daysPast I get 0 while the user entered value is clearly 7.I'm trying to determine if the inputted date "x" is within y days of the value in Cell e7 in Sheet1.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use DateDiff? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: With datediff, do I just find the difference in days and then compare the two integers?

Comment: I would look into the DateDiff and DateAdd functions...  Can you post more of your code that are calling these routines?

Comment: @B Hart If marketmonitor.Cells(i, 4) <> "" And IsDate(marketmonitor.Cells(i, 4)) Then
            If isFutureDate(marketmonitor.Cells(i, 4)) Then

Answer (score 0):

Try this (worked for me):

```
Function isFutureDate(x As Date) As Boolean
```

and

```
Function isPastDate(x As Date) As Boolean
```

and

call them like this:

```
=isFutureDate("11/01/2014")

=isPastDate("10/28/2014")
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch when I run it. However, I checked and made sure all my entries I'm inputting were in the date format.

Comment: you have to type in correct sequence of date of your system. mine is mmddyyyy, yours may be ddmmyyyy. If not worked, try remove the double quotes while typing date.

Comment: I'm actually using this function inside another subroutine where I loop through a column of dates and pull that in. It works when I use the function in my worksheet but not when I use it with the subroutine.

Comment: You can use debug.print or msgbox to check if function is working inside your sub. But you had to post full question if you had problem with your sub or something else.

Comment: evaluate functions as above inside any available cell inside your file to test them. If you have other issues, post a new question and post a link to this question in that question.

Comment: Also post new question's link here to maintain continuity as well. And upvote/mark as answer if you get workable answer for this specific question.